# Regex to match backslash inside a string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to match the following strings:

- `this\test_`
- `_thistes\t`
- `_t\histest`

In other words, the allowed strings have ONLY a backslash, splitting 2 substrings which can contain numbers, letters and _ characters.

I tried the following regex, testing it on http://regexhero.net/tester/:
`^[a-zA-Z_][\\\]?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$`

Unfortunately, it recognizes also the following not allowed strings:

- `this\\`
- `_\`
- `_\w\s\x`

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex can mean two things, depending on whether you are declaring it as a raw string or as a normal string.

Using:

```
"^[a-zA-Z_][\\\]?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$"
```

Will not match any of your test examples, since this will match, in order:

- `^` beginning of string,
- `[a-zA-Z_]` 1 alpha character or underscore,
- `[\\\]?` 1 optional backslash,
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` at least 1 alphanumeric and/or underscore characters,
- `$` end of string

If you use it as a raw string (which is how regexhero interpreted it and indicated by the `@` sign before the string starts) is:

```
@"^[a-zA-Z_][\\\]?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$"
```

- `^` beginning of string,
- `[a-zA-Z_]` 1 alpha character or underscore,
- `[\\\]?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` one or more characters being; backslash, `]`, `?`, alphanumeric and underscore,
- `$` end of string.

---

So what you actually need is either:

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\\\[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$"
```

(Two pairs of backslashes become two literal backslashes, which will be interpreted by the regex engine as an escaped backslash; hence 1 literal backslash)

Or

```
@"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$"
```

(No backslash substitution performed, so the regex engine directly interprets the escaped backslash)

Note that I added the numbers in the first character class to allow it to match numbers like you requested and added the `+` quantifier to allow it to match more than one character before the backslash.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this seems to be the most complete one between the others.
I needed to modify the regex to the following one, to match the fact the '\' char is optional:
^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$

I found that 1 character strings are not matched (e.g.: "a", "b", "9" etc. are not recognized). Why? Is it possible to fix that?

Comment: @Zanzi Sorry for not replying earlier. I got stuck with a big task to do :s If you want to avoid matching a\ you might want to use this instead: `@"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?:\\[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$)?"`

Comment: Maybe the following is better:
^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?:\\[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$)?$

Your solution also matches part of strings, instead I need to match the whole string.

Comment: @Zanzi Oops, I have put the closing paren at the wrong position. The `$` shouldn't be inside, but completely at the end. Sorry about that.

Comment: @AJ_ Thank you for downvoting and saying the answer is wrong by using a website that users Javascript while the answer is for C#

Comment: @Jerry, that is fair. I assumed all regex was the same. I also tried, http://regexstorm.net/tester, using pattern "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\\\[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$"
 and input of "this\test"

Comment: @AJ_ I'm 100% sure that tester accepts raw strings by default, that's why in my answer there are two versions of the same regex. If you don't believe me, here's a full code snippet and not some random tester on the internet: https://ideone.com/UnxOr5 (I hope you know how these work)

Answer (score 2):

Don't make the `\` as optional. The below regex won't allow two or more `\` backslashes and asserts that there must be atleast one word character present before and after to the `\` symbol.

```
@"^\w+\\\w+$"
```

OR

```
@"^[A-Za-z0-9_]+\\[A-Za-z0-9_]+$"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qM2pT8/5)

Comment: errr... `\w` means a whole lot more than that. as I understand it. "A word character. A character in the input string can belong to any of the Unicode categories that are appropriate for characters in words. For more information, see Word Character." - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx . Best example is yours will match accented characters and such like whereas the original will not. (of note is that the demo site you posted does not do c# regex matching).

Comment: I thought c# regex was normally put inside a verbatim string. So i posted only the regex. For more clarification, i put them into `@""`

Comment: see the revisions, op's original regex is `^[a-zA-Z_][\]?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$`, chris edited it to `^[a-zA-Z_][\\\]?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$`. So it means op will pass the regex within a verbatim string.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Chris did not edit the regex. Only formatting (backticks and indent was added).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to fix up your regex is the following:

`^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$`

This breaks down to:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-zA-Z0-9_]+            any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z',
                           '0' to '9', '_' (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \\                       '\'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-zA-Z0-9_]+            any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z',
                           '0' to '9', '_' (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Explanation courtesy of http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl

As you can see we have the same pattern before and after the backslash (since you indicated they should both be letters, numbers and underscores) with the + modifier meaning at least one. Then in the middle there is just the backslash which is compulsory.

Since it is unclear whether when you said "letters" you meant the basic alphabet or if you meant anything that is letter like (most obviously accented characters but also any other alphabet, etc.) then you may want to expand your set of characters by using something like `\w` as Avinash Raj suggests. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#WordCharacter for more info on what the "word character" covers.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this should work if i understood everything you wanted.

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)
```

Comment: You'll want to anchor that to the beginning and end of the string to make sure you don't just match a substring of the tested string.